# condition in if statement (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

how to detect the the type of file whether the file is pdf or jpg? I try like statement below, but it  only detect .jpg file.

```
if (file[i] == 'pdf'||file[i] == 'jpg')  {
    //
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but it only read jpg"?

Comment: I am not sure if JavaScript can detect file type from contents, it would more likely be from extension.

Comment: How is `file[i]` set? Is it going to be a string that contains a file type? If so, that if test should work; if not, it won't.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the file extension using

```
var extn = file[i].split('.').pop();
```

and check your condition whether the extension is PDF, JPG or any other for sake.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If we take file name as file,

```
string[] substrings = file.split('.');
var extension = substrings[1];
var pdf = 'pdf';
var jpg = 'jpg';
if((extension == pdf )|| (extension == jpg)){
(condition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified where these file names come from, so there are several possible scenarios.

If you are referring to hyperlinks and you want to do something only to the links that point to, `.pdf` or `.jpg` files, you don't need to look at all the links and test for `.pdf` files or `.jpg` files, you can just scan only for `.pdf` and `.jpg` files like this:

```js
var files = document.querySelectorAll("a[href$='.pdf'], a[href$='.jpg']");
console.log("There are " + files.length  + " .pdf and/or .jpg links.");
Array.prototype.slice.call(files).forEach(function(file){
  console.log(file.getAttribute("href"));
});
```

```html
<a href="someImage.jpg">Click</a>
<a href="someImage.gif">Click</a>
<a href="someFile.pdf">Click</a>
<a href="somefile2.pdf">Click</a>
<a href="someImage.png">Click</a>
```

If you have an array of file names, you can get the `.pdf` and `.jpg` names like this:

```js
var files = [ "file1.png", "file2.jpg", "file3.pdf", "file4.JPG", "file5.gif" ];

var matchedFiles = files.filter(function(file){
  var ext = file.substr(file.length - 4, file.length);
  if(ext.toLowerCase() === ".pdf" || ext.toLowerCase() === ".jpg"){
    return file;
  }
});

console.log(matchedFiles);
```